# Ng-repeat hiding radio button based on Radio answer selected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need some help trying to figure out how to hide answers if other answers are selected when items are in ng-repeat block.  For instance in the below code.  If a user selects answer11 in Question 1, then in Question 2 only answer21 is available from the possible answers listed under the question.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);


app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {


    $scope.questions = [{
        questiontxt: 'Please select your Age range',
        qid: 1234,
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer11",
          aId: 83493
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer12",
          aId: 1223
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer13",
          aId: 1223
        }]
      },
      {
        questiontxt: 'Please select your favorite activity',
        qid: 5678,
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer21",
          aId: 90886
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer22",
          aId: 67107
        }]
      },
      {
        questiontxt: 'Please select your favorite food',
        qid: 4321,
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer31",
          aId: 32342
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer32",
          aId: 79130
        }]
      }
    ];
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
    <div class="row">
      <br/><span>Q{{$index+1}}. {{question.questiontxt}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="answer in question.Answer">
      <input type="radio" value="{{answer.answertxt}}{{$parent.$index}}" ng-model="question.selectedAnswer" ng-value="{{answer.answertxt}}" />{{answer.answertxt}}
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight-forward way would be to augment your 'answer' data structures with two new arrays, 'hides' and 'removes', which upon selection would disable or by case remove the targeted answers of other questions. For example,

```
...
Answer: [{
  answertxt: "answer11",
  aId: 83493,
  hides: [{
    qid: 5678,
    aId: 67107
  }],
  removes: [{
    qid: 4321,
    aId: 32342
  }]
},
...
```

answer11 hides answer22 and removes answer31.

Your html would then boil down to the following display logic:

```
<div ng-repeat="answer in question.Answer">
  <div ng-if="!answer.isRemoved">
    <input type="radio"
           ng-change="select(question, answer)"
           ng-disabled="answer.isDisabled"
           ng-model="question.selectedAnswer" 
           ng-value="answer.answertxt" />
    <strike ng-if="answer.isDisabled">{{answer.answertxt}}</strike>
    <span ng-if="!answer.isDisabled">{{answer.answertxt}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

where the `isRemoved` and `isDisabled` flags are set on answer selection in `select(question, answer)`.

Full working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);


app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    
    function getAnswer(qid, aid) {
        var qs = $scope.questions, q;
        for (var i = 0; i < qs.length; ++i) {
          if (qs[i].qid === qid) {
            q = qs[i];
            break;
          }
        }
        if (q) {
          var as = q.Answer;
          for (i = 0; as.length; ++i) {
            if (as[i].aId === aid) {
              return as[i];
            }
          }
        }
    }
    
    function doHide(q, a) {
      if (a.hides && a.hides.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < a.hides.length; ++i) {
          var h = a.hides[i],
              answer = getAnswer(h.qid, h.aId);
          if (answer) {
            answer.isDisabled = (q.selectedAnswer == a.answertxt);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    function doRemove(q, a) {
      if (a.removes && a.removes.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < a.removes.length; ++i) {
          var r = a.removes[i],
              answer = getAnswer(r.qid, r.aId);
          if (answer) {
            answer.isRemoved = (q.selectedAnswer == a.answertxt);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    $scope.select = function (q, a) {
      var as = q.Answer;
      
      for (var i = 0; i < as.length; ++i) {
        var answer = as[i];
        doHide(q, answer);
        doRemove(q, answer);
      }
    };

    $scope.questions = [{
        questiontxt: 'Please select your Age range',
        qid: 1234,
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer11",
          aId: 83493,
          hides: [{
            qid: 5678,
            aId: 67107
          }],
          removes: [{
            qid: 4321,
            aId: 32342
          }]
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer12",
          aId: 1223,
          removes: [{
            qid: 4321,
            aId: 79130
          }]
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer13",
          aId: 1223
        }]
      },
      {
        questiontxt: 'Please select your favorite activity',
        qid: 5678,
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer21",
          aId: 90886
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer22",
          aId: 67107
        }]
      },
      {
        questiontxt: 'Please select your favorite food',
        qid: 4321,
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer31",
          aId: 32342
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer32",
          aId: 79130
        }]
      }
    ];
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
    <div class="row">
      <br/><span>Q{{$index+1}}. {{question.questiontxt}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="answer in question.Answer">
      <div ng-if="!answer.isRemoved">
        <input type="radio"
          ng-change="select(question, answer)"
          ng-disabled="answer.isDisabled"
          ng-model="question.selectedAnswer" 
          ng-value="answer.answertxt" />
          <strike ng-if="answer.isDisabled">{{answer.answertxt}}</strike>
          <span ng-if="!answer.isDisabled">{{answer.answertxt}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i tried your solution, what i noticed while it did hide and remove the element, if the user selected the answer before it is hid/removed it shows up as apart of the selectedAnswers.  but it was a helpful starting point

Answer (score 1):

Could add a property like:

```
disables: [{ selectedAnswer: 83493,otherQ: 5678, otherAnswerId: 90886 }]
```

to each question along with `ng-disbled` and `ng-change` to each radio

The methodology is to look at all the `disables` above and then check the corresponding other question and other answer and see if the currently selected answer matches the `selectedAnswer` in the disable object

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);


app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.disableMatches = function(question, answer) {
      let selectedId = question.selectedAnswer;
      question.disables.forEach(function(o) {
        let otherQ = $scope.questions.find(function(q) {
          return q.qid == o.otherQ
        });
        let otherAnswer = otherQ.Answer.find(function(ans) {
          return ans.aId === o.otherAnswerId
        })
        otherAnswer.disabled = selectedId == o.selectedAnswer;
      });
    }

    $scope.questions = [{
        questiontxt: 'Please select your Age range',
        qid: 1234,
        disables: [{
          selectedAnswer: 83493,
          otherQ: 5678,
          otherAnswerId: 90886
        }],
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer11  Disables answer 21",
          aId: 83493
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer12",
          aId: 1223
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer13",
          aId: 1223
        }]
      },
      {
        questiontxt: 'Please select your favorite activity',
        qid: 5678,
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer21",
          aId: 90886
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer22",
          aId: 67107
        }]
      },
      {
        questiontxt: 'Please select your favorite food',
        qid: 4321,
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer31",
          aId: 32342
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer32",
          aId: 79130
        }]
      }
    ];
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
    <div class="row">
      <br/><span>Q{{$index+1}}. {{question.questiontxt}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="answer in question.Answer">
      <label>
      <input type="radio"
      name="radio{{$parent.$index}}"
      ng-change="disableMatches(question)"
      ng-disabled="answer.disabled"
      ng-model="question.selectedAnswer" 
      ng-value="{{answer.aId}}" />{{answer.answertxt}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```