# Clear Radio Button on ng-disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is how I a implemented my code which I modified from [Ng-repeat hiding radio button based on other radio answers selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47497259/ng-repeat-hiding-radio-button-based-on-other-radio-answers-selected/47498129#47498129). What I need help with is clearing the radio button when it is removed/disabled == true of that answer.

If the user starts with Q3 and selects answer31 then goes back to Q1 and selects answer11, the question.selectedAnswer  still shows up as answer31.

Any help is appreciated

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);


app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    
    function getAnswer(qid, aid) {
        var qs = $scope.questions, q;
        for (var i = 0; i < qs.length; ++i) {
          if (qs[i].qid === qid) {
            q = qs[i];
            break;
          }
        }
        if (q) {
          var as = q.Answer;
          for (i = 0; as.length; ++i) {
            if (as[i].aId === aid) {
              return as[i];
            }
          }
        }
    }
    
    
    function doRemove(q, a) {
      if (a.removes && a.removes.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < a.removes.length; ++i) {
          var r = a.removes[i],
              answer = getAnswer(r.qid, r.aId);
          if (answer) {
            answer.isDisabled = (q.selectedAnswer == a.answertxt);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    $scope.select = function (q, a) {
      var as = q.Answer;
      
      for (var i = 0; i < as.length; ++i) {
        var answer = as[i];
        doRemove(q, answer);
      }
    };

    $scope.questions = [{
        questiontxt: 'Please select your Age range',
        qid: 1234,
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer11",
          aId: 83493,
          hides: [{
            qid: 5678,
            aId: 67107
          }],
          removes: [{
            qid: 4321,
            aId: 32342
          }]
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer12",
          aId: 1223,
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer13",
          aId: 1223
        }]
      },
      {
        questiontxt: 'Please select your favorite activity',
        qid: 5678,
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer21",
          aId: 90886
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer22",
          aId: 67107
        }]
      },
      {
        questiontxt: 'Please select your favorite food',
        qid: 4321,
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer31",
          aId: 32342
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer32",
          aId: 79130
        }]
      }
    ];
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
    <div class="row">
      <br/><span>Q{{$index+1}}. {{question.questiontxt}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="answer in question.Answer">
      <div ng-if="!answer.isDisabled">
        <input type="radio"
          ng-change="select(question, answer)"
          ng-disabled="answer.isDisabled"
          ng-model="question.selectedAnswer" 
          ng-value="answer.answertxt" />
          <span>{{answer.answertxt}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**update**

I want to make sure my intent is clear.

If the user starts on Q1 and selects "answer11" in Q1 you can see that in Q3 "answer31" disappears. Making it not possible for the user to select "answer31"

But if the user starts on Q3 and selects "answer31" in Q3, the answer is still selected even though the user selects "answer11" in Q1 (which makes the answer disappear). In the backend "answer31" is still selected.

Please let me know if this makes sense. Looking at the one of the answers received, the solution might be to hide Q3 until a selection is made in Q1. Which might be a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your purpose exactly.

But I've made a fiddle that might be able to help you.

[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/r840y7L7/2/)

```
$scope.showQuestion = function(index, answer){
    $scope.answerArr.length = index;
    var questionNum = 0;    //  for innitializing radio after this question
    angular.forEach($scope.questions, function(question){
        if(index < questionNum){
            delete question.selectedAnswer;
        }
        questionNum++;
    });
    $scope.answerArr.push(answer);
};
```

Is this what you want to do?

If not, give me some feedback.

I hope I've understood what you want and this fiddle is near from perfect for your purpose. :)

.

.

.

**UPDATED**

First, sorry for my misunderstanding of your question.

I think maybe this time, the fiddle what I'll bring to you, is almost proper to your intent.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/bf1ad2xe/9/)

You can test check boxes of 'Q1' or 'Q2'.

But in this fiddle, the way handling `$scope.questions` is different from yours.

So it might be too hard to understanding my codes, even though I've added comment each lines.

Moreover, It's been a short time I've started programming, you might think this is a kind of 'hard coding'. :D

.

.

**UPDATED2**

[This is finally well working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/bf1ad2xe/19/)

I just hope this can be a little helpful for you, or brought a good hint to you.

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution.  It didn't cross my mind to hide the question before showing the question but this might be a solution.  So based on what the user selects on Q1, I want on Q2 one of the answers to be removed so the user cannot select it.

Comment: Ah, you mean all questions should be shown and when user didn't select Q1, Q2 and Q3 have to be disabled, then user select Q1 and Q2, Q3 still have to be disabled, right?

Comment: And did you find solution of this?

Comment: No I haven't found a solution to this.  I think based on your response, I am going to create a new question, and have people respond to that. you have shown me a new way to approach the problem.   Yes, I was showing all the questions and answers at first.  If the user selected in Q1, answer11 then in Q3 answer31 would disappear, this worked only okay.   If the user decided to go out of order, and start with Q3 and selected answer31 and then select Q1 answer 11, Q3 answer31 would disappear but in the backend answer31 is still selected.

Comment: @user990951 Oh, I'v been misunderstanding until now.. I think I got it! From now on I'll try to find the right solution and if I get it, share it to you. :)

Comment: @user990951 oh.. wait a minute. This has some problems.. T.T I'm trying to fix them.

Comment: @user990951 I think this'll take times.. sorry for my wrong answer. ASAP I'll fix it.

Comment: @user990951 Finally, I've made fiddle which works good! Check fiddle below 'UPDATE2'.

Comment: @user990951 Thanks. But there's still errors. when you check 'Answer12' and 'Answer21', then 'Answer41' and 'Answer42' is disabled. but when you make disabling 'Answer21' by click 'Answer13', 'Answer41' still disabled.

Comment: @user990951 Oh, this was caused by order in 'selectAnswer' function. I've modified fiddle and this works well. It's all done. :)

Comment: well done. you still got me curious on hiding the question based on a user radio selection. I am trying to see if i can solve it on my own. Thanks again